# Issue with SQL Loader loading .CSV file to Oracle 12c Table

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm running into an error while trying to load an oracle 12c table from .CSV file in Linux environment.

Control File:

```
load data
infile '/opt/Infor/Marketing/10.1.0.0/custom/OUTBOUND_SPAM_COMPLAINTS_20230_TEST1.CSV' "str ';\r\n'"
badfile 'spam.bad'
append
into table EM10SCHEMA.UNSUBSCRIBEENTRY_STAGE
fields terminated by "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(EMAIL char(4000), created "to_date(:CREATED,'ddmmyyyy hh24:mi:ss')", UNSUBSCRIBED, ID, MODIFIED
```

Sample .CSV data:

```
EMAIL,CREATED,UNSUBSCRIBED,ID,MODIFIED
"nari_90_09@hotmail.com","2022-06-23 07:26:38","Y","263115","2022-06-23 07:29:25"
```

Error log:

> ```
> SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Mar 1 23:35:13 2023
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
>
> Control File:   /opt/Infor/Marketing/10.1.0.0/custom/spam_complaints.ldr
> Data File:      /opt/Infor/Marketing/10.1.0.0/custom/OUTBOUND_SPAM_COMPLAINTS_20230_TEST1.CSV
>   File processing option string: "str ';^M
> '"
>   Bad File:     spam.bad
>   Discard File:  none specified
>
>  (Allow all discards)
>
> Number to load: ALL
> Number to skip: 0
> Errors allowed: 50
> Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
> Continuation:    none specified
> Path used:      Conventional
>
> Table EM10SCHEMA.UNSUBSCRIBEENTRY_STAGE, loaded from every logical record.
> Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND
> TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect
>
>    Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
> ------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
> EMAIL                               FIRST  4000   ,       CHARACTER
>     Enclosure string : '""'
> CREATED                              NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
>     Enclosure string : '""'
>     SQL string for column : "to_date(:CREATED,'ddmmyyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
> UNSUBSCRIBED                         NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
>     Enclosure string : '""'
> ID                                   NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
>     Enclosure string : '""'
> MODIFIED                             NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER
>     Enclosure string : '""'
>
> value used for ROWS parameter changed from 64 to 50
> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table EM10SCHEMA.UNSUBSCRIBEENTRY_STAGE, column CREATED.
> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
> ```

Any feedback on how fix the SQLLDR error would appreciated.

Thanks,
Sof

To load the .CSV data into an oracle table (See DDL below)

```
EMAIL         VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
CREATED       DATE,
UNSUBSCRIBED  CHAR(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
ID            NUMBER(19)                      NOT NULL,
MODIFIED      DATE                            NOT NULL
```

Thanks,
Sof

Comment: You'll have to look at your data. Either there is some bogus character in the CREATED position, or you have a " embedded in your EMAIL (first column) that is closing that prematurely and then trying to read the rest of the email as a date.

Answer (score 1):

Your `to_date` filter is `ddmmyyyy hh24:mi:ss` but your data is formatted with dashes in the date, and with the parts in reverse order: `2022-06-23 07:26:38`.

Change your `to_date` filter to `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`.